Error message: Coefficient : 0 is not a valid variable in DSolve
I have a simple differential equation
test1[x_] = 
 DSolveValue[{f''[x] + Log[x]*f[x] == 0, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == -1}, 
  f[x], x]

which for some reason gives me an error "Coefficient : 0 is not a valid variable". (Same thing happens if I do not specify initial values. Or initial values at points other than 0.)
This is due to the Log[x], since replacing it with another function such as $1/$x (without initial values) or $e^x$ works fine, although I don't really get what is so wrong with log. NDSolve (and moving the initial conditions a bit) works "alright", with some warning that is circumvented if I start a bit right from 0:
NDSolveValue[{f''[x] + Log[x]*f[x] == 0, f[10^-10] == 1, 
  f'[10^-10] == -1}, f[x], {x, 0, 2}]

"The function value {-1.0000000024048359,Indeterminate} is not a list \ of numbers with dimensions {2} at {x,f[x],f^\[Prime][x]} = \ {0.,1.0000000001,-1.0000000024048359}"
But it gives me anyways a solution.
Does anyone know how I can make Mathematica solve this ODE? I wanna check on the sensitivity of the pole here.

The NDSolve works. You get an error because {x, 0, 2} asks it to integrate to x == 0, and Log[x] is undefined at x == 0. The DSolve approach looks like a bug...maybe. You have the same problem with the initial condition (x == 0).

@MichaelE2 yes, I noted that it works for NDSolve without warning if one goes a bit to the right. I just wanted to show that it is ok numerically. If this is a bug, then do you have any idea how I can analyse the error I make when I change my ODE to something with $\log(x+\epsilon)$ in dependence of $\epsilon$ if I solve it numerically? The subtlety is here of course that I cannot trust the numerics for such a singular thing, i.e. I don't know if NDSolve doesn't implicitly already assume some $\epsilon>0$

I don't really know. I think DSolve cannot solve the ODE, but I'm not sure. Is there a known solution? DSolve tries many known strategies for solving 2nd order linear DEs. One of them causes the buggy error message and fails. The other methods just fail, which is normal. — The NDSolve solution should be ok. It stops when it can't reduce the step size any further to make the numerical error acceptable. Of course, it's using polynomial interpolants to approximate a pole, so the last step or two might be of lower quality than specified by PrecisionGoal and AccuracyGoal.

@MichaelE2 I don't know whether a solution exists. I was hoping Mathematica would cover many of the tried functions instead.

there is no analytic solution to this.  with or without IC. Not even to f''[x] + g[x]*f[x] == 0  Maple gives answer to your ode in terms of DESol which basically means no solution found. But it is a bug in Mathematica to give Coefficient : 0 is not a valid variable message. Please report to WRI.

@Nasser how do you report to WRI (and whats that? Wolfram research institute?)

You could just email supprt@wolfram.com with this problem. THat is all. You will get back email with case number for this bug.
